# Is there a grey area between substance noun and object noun?

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

Is there a grey area between substance noun and object noun?

I mean, are there any English words that mean ‘substance or object’?

If so, should I use an indefinite article, or not?

Comment: If you think there is a grey area, can you give some examples of the kind of words you are thinking of?

Comment: @Kate Bunting I think “explosive” is the one. some substance can be (an) explosive, and a bomb can be (an) explosive.

Comment: explosive, any substance or device that can be made to produce a volume of rapidly expanding gas in an extremely brief period.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lots of nouns can be used for both the substance and a particular object made of that substance.

> Chocolate :  A sweet substance made with cocoa, sugar and fats
>
> A chocolate : a single candy made with chocolate

Your example works differently.  The countable form refers to a type of explosive.

> How much explosive do we need to blow up this building?
>
> Gunpowder is an explosive. Gunpowder, Dynamite and C4 are all explosives.

But note that an object made with explosive, isn't "an explosive"  It is a bomb, or a charge, or a device.

You use the article when using the noun as a countable noun to refer to an object made from the substance. Or you use it to refer to a type of the substance. Whether "A ...." is an object, type, or either depends on context and idiom.

> This window is made of glass  (substance, uncountable)
>
> A glass filled with water was on the table.  (object countable)
>
> Borosilicate is a glass with great strength (type of substance, countable)

Comment: Also, gunpowder, when confined and ignited, is explosive (adjective).